# Where do I add my .eslintrc.js file in a Vue Project?

Tags: vuejs2, eslintrc

I don't like that it turns off `console.log()` but wherever I put my eslint file Vue just doesn't seem to know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add my `.eslint.js` file in the project root folder (at the same level of `package.json`) no in the src folder.

If you are not sure where to put such configuration files you may want to check out the updated [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) which does a lot of annoying work for you and this [blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-cli-3-the-deep-dive-41dff070ac4a).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since I'm new to using eslint the rules are actually in `package.json` in the vue project directory as well. I didn't think to look there first...